# Declaration conflicts between time.h and linux/time.h prevent me from using CLOCK_TAI

Tags: c, linux, time, time.h

I would like to use

```
#include <time.h>
clock_gettime(CLOCK_TAI, &...);
```

but unfortunately `CLOCK_TAI` is not defined in stock *time.h* header (in openSUSE 13.2 at least). It is however defined in *linux/time.h* and actually supported by the operating system. But if I include the latter header, it provokes a bunch of declaration conflicts — versus both *time.h* and *bits/types.h*. Including only the *linux/time.h* does not help, as *time.h* and/or *bits/types.h* will be implicitly included by common headers, like *unistd.h* or *stdlib.h*, anyway.

---

So I tried to resolve conflicts manually. Particularly, the first compiler error message was about `timespec` redeclaration, so I wrote in my code:

```
#include <time.h>
#if defined(__timespec_defined) && !defined(_STRUCT_TIMESPEC)
    #define _STRUCT_TIMESPEC
#endif
#include <linux/time.h>
```

It worked, but not without yet another conflict with `itimerspec` redeclaration, which is declared unconditionally in both headers and is not concluded with definitions of any include guards. So I decided to ban implicit *time.h* inclusion altogether:

```
#include <linux/time.h>
#ifndef _TIME_H
    #define _TIME_H
#endif
```

This continued with compiler complaining about `timeval` redeclaration. So I banned implicit *bits/types.h* inclusion as well:

```
#include <linux/time.h>
#ifndef _TIME_H
    #define _TIME_H
#endif
#ifndef _BITS_TYPES_H
    #define _BITS_TYPES_H
#endif
```

Alright, but this removes important basic declarations as well, upon which common types like `size_t` are based. So I tried to go in the opposite direction and disable *linux/types.h* inclusion:

```
#ifndef _LINUX_TYPES_H
    #define _LINUX_TYPES_H
#endif
#include <linux/time.h>
#ifndef _TIME_H
    #define _TIME_H
#endif
```

As you can guess, it resulted in system-specific types like `__kernel_time_t` being missing, which leaded to inability to declare `timespec` and so on.

---

Thus I am wondering: is it at all possible to use *linux/…* headers in combination with *stdlib.h* and other commonly included files? Are there other ways to access system-specific `CLOCK_TAI` value?

Comment: If updating glibc isn't a possibility, then define it by yourself (`#if defined(__linux__) && !defined(CLOCK_TAI)`). I doubt its value (`11`) will change. But maybe someone else has a better solution.

Comment: @cremno I also thought that `CLOCK_xxx` values are universal invariants — until realizing that on Cygwin, for example, `CLOCK_REALTIME == 1` and `CLOCK_MONOTONIC == 4`, while usually (on *nix systems) `CLOCK_REALTIME == 0`, `CLOCK_MONOTONIC == 1` and `CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW == 4`. So making assumptions about enumeration values is not a portable approach.

Comment: Just for clarification, is `CLOCK_TAI` not defined in time.h, or is it *conditionally* defined there?  If conditional, and failing, you could pursue that route.

Comment: @donjuedo Good idea, but unfortunately they are all defined in a single `#ifdef __USE_POSIX199309` block, and there are only codes 0 to 9 there.